# How do i find the middle point/s coordinates between two points?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method:

```
private static List<PointF> ExtendPoints(PointF pt1, PointF pt3)
        {
            float x = (Math.Max(pt1.X, pt3.X) - Math.Min(pt1.X, pt3.X)) / 2 + Math.Min(pt1.X, pt3.X);
            float y = (Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt3.Y) - Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt3.Y)) / 2 + Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt3.Y);
            var pt2 = new PointF(x, y);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt1);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt2);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt3);
            return extendedPoints;
        }
```

I give two points and it return a List with 3 points the new point pt2 is in the middle.
The calculation is just to find the excat coordinates between the distance of the two given points.

Now i want to make that it will return a List with 4 points.

pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4

Thr List format will be: pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 and the new points are pt3 and pt4.
So now i need to divide it by 3 ? I need to find the exact two points between the given two points.

This is what i did but its not giving the right result:

```
private static List<PointF> ExtendPoints(PointF pt1, PointF pt4)
        {
            float x = (Math.Max(pt1.X, pt4.X) - Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X)) / 3 + Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X); // Could also doing: (pt1.X + pt3.X) / 2;
            float y = (Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt4.Y) - Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y)) / 3 + Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y);
            var pt2 = new PointF(x, y);
            float a = (Math.Max(pt1.X, pt4.X) - Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X)) / 2 / 3 + Math.Min(pt1.X, pt4.X);
            float b = (Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt4.Y) - Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y)) / 2 / 3 + Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt4.Y);
            var pt3 = new PointF(a, b);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt1);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt2);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt3);
            extendedPoints.Add(pt4);
            return extendedPoints;
        }
```

The List return extendedPoints contain 4 indexs in each index there is x and y.

Then im doing in the construction:

```
point1 = new Point(80, 80);
point2 = new Point(280, 300);
extendedPoints = ExtendPoints(point1, point2);
```

Then in the paint event i want to display the List the points returned:

```
foreach (PointF pt in extendedPoints)
            {
                e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X, pt.Y, 4f, 4f);
            }
```

But i see only 3 points not 4.

So where is the bug ? Something in the method with the calculations is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dividing the distance travelled by 1/3 and 2/3 on each axis will give you the intermediate points on the straight line between the two endpoints. Basic geometry.

Comment: keshlam so i keep the two x and y i have now divided by 2. And add two new variablex for example a and b and this time divide it by 3 ?

Comment: If you want to divide the line into three equal segments, ignore or discard the 1/2 result and instead divide by 1/3 for one point and 2/3 for the other point.